# How many ways are there to place these books on the shelves?

Tags: permutations

You are given 5 books and 7 bookshelves. How many ways are there to place these books
on the shelves? (The order on the shelves matters.)

I want to say $7^5$ since there are 7 possible shelves and five different options to select from books that will be placed.

Could some one explain why my answer is wrong, and what the right answer is?

Comment: Use Stars and Bars theorem, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you chose Bookshelf 1 five times. That would be just one of the possibilities you've enumerated. But there are 5! = 120 ways to arrange those 5 books on the first bookshelf.

One way to do it:
Consider the different shelves as 6 "boundaries" to insert between your books.
Thus there are 11 things to order, but 6 of them are equivalent.
So there are $\frac{11!}{6!}$ ways.